# Transforming random number into normal distrubution

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I am looking to transform a random number into a normal distribution between 1-20. I have been looking to implement the box muller transformation to do so. But can someone point me an easy way to do so using solidity?

Comment: If the random number itself is in normal distribution, then you can use `x % 20 + 1`.

Comment: @goodvibration No the random number is in a uniform distribution.